# How to detect file system fault or unformatted partition in a user space program via a C api?

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I have a SD card in `/dev/mmcblk0`, with one `vfat` partition at `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, mounted at `/media/mmcblk0p1`.

When my application starts up, I want it to check the file system in that partition, try to repair it, and notify user if there are non-repairable errors, and possibly recommend a re-format.

This SD card is installed internally, not removable, and is shipped with the product. I want to keep it as healthy as possible to avoid a customer service nightmare.

[fsck.vfat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck.vfat)'s exit status doesn't distinguish between "No recoverable errors have been detected." and "Non-recoverable errors have been detected.", so it doesn't exactly meet the need here.

Comment: Well if there are errors it can't be mounted, can it? So just check if the device is mounted?

Comment: That is strange because manual(8) says "No recoverable error" should return 0 and "Recoverable errors or fs inconsistency" (fs inconsistency is your "Non-recoverable errors" should return 1.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So if card exists but isn't/cannot be mounted, then there's an fs error?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès So I should run `fsck.vfat`, if returns 0 then everything is OK, if 1 then I should run it again. If the second time it returns 0, then all recoverable errors are fixed, everything is OK, if 1, it means some errors are not fixed during the second run, so "non-recoverable error detected". Is this logic complete?

Comment: You can use option `-Va` to have non-interactive repair and automatic check-and-repair if problem.